# itextsharp.text.document is not defined

Tags: .net, vb.net, itext7

I needed to re-write a VB.NET solution from scratch due to a compiler error that I couldn't fix otherwise (VS support asked me to create the solution from scratch to see if the error goes away).

I have created a new VB.NET project and added the old forms, classes and modules.
Then I added the NuGet packages.

In my form I used

```
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser
```

I am now getting the errors

```
itextsharp.text.document is not defined
Type 'PDFWriter' is not defined
PDFContentByte is not defined.
```

in this form.

NuGet packages that I installed are iText7 7.2.3 and itext7.commons.

I don't see any difference to my previous project where I did not have these errors.

What am I not seeing / missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems I am using both

```
itext7
```

and

```
iTextSharp
```

Once I installed both from NuGet, it worked.